# One rows go under the other one on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have designed a website like this:

```
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid container-full">
    <div class="row"> <!-- Row 1-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
      <div class="first-row">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> <!-- Row 2 -->
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 righ-left-panel"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 second-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Content</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 righ-left-panel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> <!-- Row 3 -->
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 righ-left-panel"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 third-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Content</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 righ-left-panel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

It is inside a wrapper and it loads everything perfectly on big screen devices.

But doesn't work on less than 700px devices.

The third row goes exactly on second Row and fully cover it.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Here comes CSS

```
.first-row{
    background:url(../images/top-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top ;
    height: 420px;
    max-height: 420px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%
    box-shadow: 1;
}

.second-row{
    height: 610px;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 130px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px){
    .second-row{
        background: url(../images/ponebg.png) no-repeat 100% top;
        margin-top: -70px;  
        background-size: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .second-row{
        background: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

.third-row{
    max-width: 1050px;
    height: 610px;
    /*alignment: center;*/
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: just a quick note: you're missing a closing `div` just above the 2nd and 3rd `section`...

Comment: It works well with pure bootstrap css-styles. Something's wrong with css rules, that you didn't show here

Comment: Your column classes are **super-redundant**. See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the 2 rows inside your Row 2 and Row 3, not with the "main" rows, actually.

Have a look at this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Content</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">Content</div>
```

This tells twitter bootstrap to put the 2nd Content row on its own line if the screen is `sm` or `xs`. Change those column numbers for the 2 rows there to come to a total of 12, and they will remain on the same line.

You could do something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Content</div>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">Content</div>
```

Normally I'd give you a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) link to test on, but it seems to be down at this moment for some reason, so here's a jsfiddle until then: http://jsfiddle.net/pgovggjy/

**EDIT**: Following your updated question adding the CSS code, my code still works. The problem for you may be with the size / type of the images you're trying to use. You may want to upload it somewhere and provide their direct link, if it still doesn't work.

Here is a Bootply test link that you can play with: http://www.bootply.com/Apeolkpnvh

Comment: well, i gave this answer before you shared the additional CSS... let me review it now...

Comment: Thank you but I found the problem

Comment: next time make sure you describe your issue a little better (more details - the original images would have been quite important to have, for example), otherwise you can't expect a lot of people helping you...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with height of rows.
I modified CSS

```
.first-row{
    background:url(../images/top-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top ;
    max-height: 420px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%
    box-shadow: 1;
}

.second-row{
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 130px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px){
    .second-row{
        background: url(../images/ponebg.png) no-repeat 100% top;
        margin-top: -70px;  
        background-size: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .second-row{
        background: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

.third-row{
    max-width: 1050px;
    /*alignment: center;*/
    width: 80%;
}
```

I removed All of heights and it worked perfectly!